# Jquery regex range not working for password

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to pass minimum range for a password that should not be less than 3 letters, but every time my text/password gets executed.

**Below is my code:**

```
$.formUtils.addValidator({
        name: "userpassword",
        validatorFunction: function(a) {
         return !!a.match((/^\s*[A-Za-z0-9@_\./\-]{5,}+\s*$/))
        },
        errorMessage: "Please enter a valid Password for user (Special characters are not allowed apart from At sign (@),Underscore(_), Hyphen(-) and Period(.)) <br> Minimum length for password is 5",
        errorMessageKey: "badname"
    })
```

Comment: How are you calling it? Meaning, how are you passing the string in?

Comment: from the text box <input style="width:80%" class="w3-input w3-border w3-light-grey " data-validation="userpassword" type="text"  name='user_pass' id='userpassword' autofocus required />

Comment: There is an error in regex. Use `return /^[\w@.-]{3,}$/.test(a);`

Comment: The plus after } must be removed.

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @JasshhAndrews: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS regex does not support possessive quantifiers.

You may fix the pattern by removing the `+` after the limiting quantifier:

```
a.match((/^\s*[A-Za-z0-9@_.\/-]{5,}\s*$/)
```

Note that a `/` is better escaped (even though in most browsers it will work well if you keep it unescaped inside a character class), `.` does not have to be escaped inside a character class and `-` at the end of the character class does not have to be escaped.

Also, you may shorten the regex by replacing `A-Za-z0-9_` with `\w`:

```
a.match((/^\s*[\w@.\/-]{5,}\s*$/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$.formUtils.addValidator({
        name: "userpassword",
        validatorFunction: function(a) {
         return !!a.match((/^\s*[A-Za-z0-9@_\./\-]{5,}\s*$/))
        },
        errorMessage: "Please enter a valid Password for user (Special characters are not allowed apart from At sign (@),Underscore(_), Hyphen(-) and Period(.)) <br> Minimum length for password is 5",
        errorMessageKey: "badname"
    })
```

Need to remove + after }

Comment: I posted my answer, please consider upvoting/accepting since my solution worked for and I hope my answer will turn out helpful.